# Lost files while deleting users

Tags: user-profiles

I was trying to stop the need to login every time my screen went to sleep using Windows 10. I did not succeed, what I did do however was to delete my main user profile that contained all of my documents and pictures. Is there any way to recover or gain access to those files?

Comment: Does the user's folder still appear in `C:\Users`? If so, you can just look in there.

Comment: recovery software should be appropriate here

Comment: Personally, I'd go with Recuva, if the files are gone from the Users folder.